# spring boot add post to category

Tags: spring-boot

im new in spring boot i want add post to category but i a get this error

"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.global.api.model.Category` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('food')",
"path": "/api/posts"
}

this is category entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

this is post entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
```

this is post service and service implement

```
  @Override
    public Post createPost(CreatePostRequest post, Category category,  String jwt) throws Exception {
        User user = userService.findUserByJwtToken(jwt);
        Post newPost = new Post();
        newPost.setTitle(post.getTitle());
        newPost.setDescription(post.getDescription());
        newPost.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        newPost.setCategory(category);
        newPost.setUser(user);
        return postRepository.save(newPost);
    }

post service 

    public Post createPost(CreatePostRequest request, Category category, String jwt) throws Exception;
```

can any one help tell me where the problem when i create new post

{
"title":"Second post with post response class message and post object",
"description": "you can test the api here!",
"category":"food"

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a `Category` object inside `Post` class, But in the post request you are sending a category String of "food" which is wrong. the right JSON would be

```
{ "title":"Second post with post response class message and post object",
  "description": "you can test the api here!",
  "category": {"name":"food"}
}
```

this will solve the deserializer issue.

> you may run into another issue with detached object as Category is new object to database that has no Id, adding @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) will fix it for now, but I advise you to search about ManyToOne to find the best solution for you case

Comment: Wish you the best !. you can always ask questions here on stackoverflow. or contact me directly happy to help any time.